# Typescript alias not matching function signature

Tags: typescript

I have type aliases as follows

```
export type Abc = string;
export type Efg = <T>(item: T): Abc
```

Now I use that in the following:

```
export interface SomeInterface<T> {
  someField: (item?: T) => Abc;
}
```

I have a method which takes in `Efg`.

```
someMethod(methodToCall: Efg);
```

Now when I try to call `someMethod` like this I get an error

> obj.someMethod(someInterfaceObject.someField);
>
> TS2345: Argument of type `(item?: T) => string` is not assignable to parameter of type 'Efg'. Type of parameter 'item' and 'item' are incompatible. Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.

Note that this was working with typescript 1.8.9 but I am upgrading to typescript 2.4.2. Also note that I have also tried making item optional ( e. g. `item?: T`) in type `Efg` and mandatory in `SomeInterface.someField` but it gives me the same error.

Comment: What's `T`? Are you sure that's the same for both definitions?

Answer (score 0):

In orderder for `obj.someField` to conform to `SomeInterface.someField`, the `obj.someField` needs to be generic. The following shows a working example:

```
export type Abc = string;
export type Efg = <T>(item: T) => Abc;
export interface SomeInterface { someField: <T>(item: T) => Abc; }

declare class Foo {
  someMethod(methodToCall: Efg): any;
}
declare const obj: SomeInterface;
new Foo().someMethod(obj.someField); // works
```